# Show eonasdan.github datetimepicker without text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I need to show datepickers on page load, not by clicking on input or icon.
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

It's this plugin. I can't find any example for this, is this possible ?

[image]

Comment: are you going to use a hidden input to save the selection?

Comment: yes. This can be an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, you have to use the [inline option](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#inline). You can use the doc's example:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
                inline: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure since you provided the link with the actual answer, you found that the code from that page, what I copied below didn't work.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
                inline: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Your problem is the actual libraries. I tried using all the latest jquery, moment, and bootstrap libraries, which was giving me an error. So I tried the libraries that was used on the site, which works.

Here's the example:

https://jsfiddle.net/hx2xyufw/1/